# performing sum of outer products on sparse matrices

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am trying to implement the following equation using scipy's sparse package:

```
W = x[:,1] * y[:,1].T + x[:,2] * y[:,2].T + ...
```

where x & y are a nxm csc_matrix. Basically I'm trying to multiply each col of x by each col of y and sum the resulting nxn matrices together. I then want to make all non-zero elements 1.

This is my current implementation:

```
    c = sparse.csc_matrix((n, n))
    for i in xrange(0,m):
        tmp = bam.id2sym_thal[:,i] * bam.id2sym_cort[:,i].T
        minimum(tmp.data,ones_like(tmp.data),tmp.data)
        maximum(tmp.data,ones_like(tmp.data),tmp.data)

        c = c + tmp
```

This implementation has the following problems:

1. Memory usage seems to explode. As I understand it, memory should only increase as c becomes less sparse, but I am seeing that the loop starts eating up >20GB of memory with a n=10,000, m=100,000 (each row of x & y only has around 60 non-zero elements).
2. I'm using a python loop which is not very efficient.

My question: Is there a better way to do this? Controlling memory usage is my first concern, but it would be great to make it faster!

Thank you!

Comment: `x[:,i]` is going to give you the ith column of `x`, not the row

Comment: @JoshAdel: You are right, I misspoke, I meant to say multiply the columns of x by columns of y. I have updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: Your equation is a sum of inner products, not outer products. You must transpose the columns of `y`, not `x`. (Either that, or the title is wrong.)

Comment: Please edit your question to be unambiguous respect to transpose. Are you aiming to count how many times each nonzero element is summed in outer product? Thanks

Comment: @Steve: You are right Steve- I have made the correction. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that a sum of outer products in the manner you describe is simply the same as multiplying two matrices together. In other words,

```
sum_i X[:,i]*Y[:,i].T == X*Y.T
```

So just multiply the matrices together.

```
Z = X*Y.T
```

For n=10000 and m=100000 and where each column has one nonzero element in both X and Y, it computes almost instantly on my laptop.

Comment: And the last step would be to set nonzero elements to 1, like Z.data[:]= 1. Al tough it's not really clear, if this is what OP were looking for. Thanks

Comment: This is the solution I went with. Is this true for all matrices or is it dependent on how sparse my vectors are? I employed eat's advice and set all nonzero elements to one after as well. Thanks!

Comment: Let `X = [x1 x2 ... xk]` where `xi` is the i^th column in the n-by-k matrix X. Let `Y = [y1 y2 ... yk]` where `yi` is the i^th column in the m-by-k matrix Y. Then for *any* `X` and `Y`, `Z = X*Y.T = sum_i xi*yi.T`, where `Z` is n-by-m.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of memory and performance, this might be a prime candidate for using [Cython](http://cython.org/).

There is a section of the following paper describing its use with sparse scipy matricies:

http://folk.uio.no/dagss/cython_cise.pdf